# Flagging question as belonging to another SE site

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

When flagging a question Physics SE, one can select

> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

and then one further has the options to choose from

> [meta.physics.stackexchange.com](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com)
>
> [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Would it make sense to add

> [philosophy.stackexchange.com](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com)

to that list?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4144/2451

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5690/23473

Comment: Honestly, if we were going to add another site to that list, it would definitely be electrical engineering as the #2 migrated to site after Math.SE

Comment: [I've argued for SciComp migration](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5259/scicomp-migration-option) as well. This was turned down partly due to SciComp being still a beta site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migration options are rarely added unless a site has a track record of a lot of migrations to the other site, the majority of which are successful. This is to prevent uninformed migrations to sites where the question is actually off topic.

Just use a custom flag, a moderator will migrate it.

Comment: Note that philosophy is still in beta, so maybe throwing questions at them is not too good an idea, even for moderators. Honestly, the "philosophy" questions asked here are usually pretty bad (i.e. ill-formed and vague). While my (outsider's) perspective is that Philosophy.SE really will take just about anything, the philosopher in me doesn't want to load them up with even more "so I had a few beers with my buddies and we started to think about what time *really* is..." questions.

Comment: That is a good comment, Chris. I will keep that in mind, next time flagging a question.

Comment: Regardless, it's always safe to flag, and we (mods) will determine whether the question actually should be migrated or not.